# How to display content of an state variable of array type in a component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I have an array postArray which is defined in Main.js.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state ={
        step: 1, 
        // welcome
        qNumber:1,
        accountNumber:'',
        amount:'',
        txNumber:0,
        postArray : []
    }
}
```

Also in Main.js, the array is being populated by insertTx arrow function.  Need to check if this array is being populated or not...currently i dont know how to use the console.log.  This function is being called by CashDeposit.js.

```
insertTx =() => {
    // save transaction to array state
    // create copy of the array
    const copyPostArray = Object.assign([],this.state.postArray)
    // insert one element into the array
    copyPostArray.push({
        txNumber: this.txNumber,
        qNumber : this.qNumber,
        accountNumber : this.accountNumber,
        amount :   this.amount
    })
    // save the values back to array state
    this.setState({
        postArray:copyPostArray
    })
}
```

Lastly on Summary.js, which is being called by Main.js, this will display the postArray on the render().  I am confused as to how can I use the map function to populate the array before i can display the contents using .

```
return(
    <>
    <h2>Summary of Transactions</h2>
    Display content of postArray here
    <ul>
        {/* {
        {this.postArray} 
        } */}
    </ul>
    <button className="Back" onClick={this.back}>
        « Cancel
    </button>
    <button className="Next" onClick={this.continue}>
            Confirm »
    </button>
    </>
)
==========
MAIN.JS
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Welcome from './Welcome';
import Transaction from './Transaction';
import CashDeposit from './CashDeposit';
import AnotherTx from './AnotherTx';
import Summary from './Summary';
import QueNumber from './QueNumber';

export class StepForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state ={
            step: 1, 
            // welcome
            qNumber:1,
            accountNumber:'',
            amount:'',
            txNumber:0,
            postArray : []
        }
    }

    nextStep=()=> {
        const {step}=this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step + 1
        });
    }

    prevStep=() => {
        const {step}= this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step -1
        });
    }

    newClient =() => {
        const {qNumber}=this.state;
        // q number should only increment upon exit
        // save the q number on localstorage
        this.setState({
            qNumber:qNumber+1
        });
        // force the step as first step
        this.setState({
            step: 1
        });
    }

    incTxNumber =() => {
        const {txNumber}=this.state;
        this.setState({
            txNumber:txNumber+1
        });
    }

    resetInfo =() => {
//        const {accountNumber,amount}=this.state;
        this.setState({
            accountNumber:'',amount:''
            });
    }

    insertTx =() => {
        // save transaction to array state
        // create copy of the array
        const copyPostArray = Object.assign([],this.state.postArray)
        // insert one element into the array
        copyPostArray.push({
            txNumber: this.txNumber,
            qNumber : this.qNumber,
            accountNumber : this.accountNumber,
            amount :   this.amount
        })
        // save the values back to array state
        this.setState({
            postArray:copyPostArray
        })
    }

    handleChange=input=> e => {
        this.setState({[input]:e.target.value});

    }

    showStep = () => {
        const {step, accountNumber, amount}=this.state;
            // txNumber
        if (step===1)
            return (<Welcome
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />);
        if(step===2)
            return (<Transaction
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />);
        if(step===3)
            return (<CashDeposit
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                accountNumber={accountNumber}
                amount={amount}
                incTxNumber={this.incTxNumber}
                insertTx={this.insertTx}
            />);
        if(step===4)
            return (<AnotherTx
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                resetInfo={this.resetInfo}
            />);
        if(step===5)
            return (<Summary
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                postArray={this.state.postArray}
            />);
        if(step===6)
            return (<QueNumber
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                newClient={this.newClient}
                qNumber={this.state.qNumber}
            />);
    }

    render(){
        // const {step}=this.state;
        // const {qNumber}=this.state;
        // const {txNumber}=this.state;
        return(
            <>
                {/* <h2>Step {step} of 6.</h2>
                <h2>THIS IS Q NUMBER {qNumber}</h2>
                <h2>Transaction Number {txNumber}</h2> */}
                {
                this.showStep()} 
            </>
        );
    }

}

export default StepForm;
====
SUMMARY.JS
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Summary extends Component {
    continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    }

    render(){
//        const {qNumber, accountNumber, amount}=this.props;
//        console.log('our data is',this.props.data)

        // var arrayx = [1,4,9,16];
        // var array1 =  
        // const map1 = array1.map(x=>x*2);

        // console.log(map1);
        // loop thru the data array and do something with each data
        // const namesList =data.map(this.txNumber=>{console.log(this.txNumber)}
            // txNumber: this.txNumber,
            // qNumber : this.qNumber,
            // accountNumber : this.accountNumber,
            // amount :   this.amount


            const { postArray } = this.state;
            return(
              <>
                <h2>Summary of Transactions</h2>
                Display content of postArray here
                <ul>
                  {postArray.map(({ accountNumber, amount, qNumber, txNumber }) => (
                    <li key={`${accountNumber}-${txNumber}`}>
                      <div>
                        AccountNumber: {accountNumber}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        Amount: {amount}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        qNumber: {qNumber}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        txNumber: {txNumber}
                      </div>
                    </li>)
                  )}
                </ul>
                <button className="Back" onClick={this.back}>
                  « Cancel
                </button>
                <button className="Next" onClick={this.continue}>
                  Confirm »
                </button>
              </>
            )
    }
}
```

## export default Summary;

CashDeposit.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CashDeposit extends Component {
//    state={qNumber:234};
continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
        //increment the txNumber
        this.props.incTxNumber();
        this.props.insertTx();
    }

    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    }

    render(){
        const {accountNumber, amount,handleChange}=this.props;
           return(
            <>
            <h2>Cash Deposit</h2>
                {/* Queue Number: <b>{qNumber}</b> */}
                Please enter account number and amount.
            <p>
                <label>
                    Account Number
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="accountNumber"
                        value={accountNumber}
                        placeholder="Account Number"
                        onChange={handleChange('accountNumber')}
                    />
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    Amount        
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="amount"
                        value={amount}
                        placeholder="Amount"
                        onChange={handleChange('amount')}
                        />
                </label>
            </p>
            <button className="Back" onClick={this.back}>
                « Back
            </button>
            <button className="Next" onClick={this.continue}>
                    Next »
            </button>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default CashDeposit;
```

Hi @Drew no errors already but when running the code, when Summary of Transactions is displayed, it displays the following values:

Summary of Transactions

Display content of postArray here

ID: NaN
AccountNumber:
Amount:
qNumber:
txNumber:
ID: NaN
AccountNumber:
Amount:
qNumber:
txNumber:
ID: NaN

Am I doing the assignment of values on the array correctly?  I have included the CashDeposit.js component.

Comment: You might be looking for this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html ?

Comment: sorry, not sure I read that correctly... You're learning React but you don't know how to use `console.log`?

Comment: My main question is that how can i display the content of the postArray.

Comment: What are the fields that need to be printed? All of them? `txNumber`, `qNumber`, `accountNumber`, `amount`?

Comment: I need to display the content of the array postArray on the summary.js.  Indicated on the last code sample.

Answer (score 0):

[lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
const { postArray } = this.props;
return(
  <>
    <h2>Summary of Transactions</h2>
    Display content of postArray here
    <ul>
      {postArray.map(({ accountNumber, amount, qNumber, txNumber }) => (
        <li key={`${accountNumber}-${txNumber}`}>
          <div>AccountNumber: {accountNumber}</div>
          <div>Amount: {amount}</div>
          <div>qNumber: {qNumber}</div>
          <div>txNumber: {txNumber}</div>
        </li>
      ))} 
    </ul>
    <button className="Back" onClick={this.back}>
      « Cancel
    </button>
    <button className="Next" onClick={this.continue}>
      Confirm »
    </button>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Tried this but encountered parsing error on the right curly brace before the </ul> tag.

Comment: Apologies, missed a closing `)` for the map function.

Comment: Hi @Drew Just added right parenthesis after the </li> tag.  But i encountered another problem.  const { postArray } = this.state; Error was encountered- TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'postArray' of 'this.state' as it is null.

Comment: Your state is null? Well that isn't right. It is defined in your constructor. Something else is happening, can you update question with entire `Main.js` component code? **Wait, is the Summary of Transactions a different component?** Please also include `Summary.js`

Comment: Updated the post with the main and summary.

Comment: @Concorde Ok, what I suspected, `Summary` is a stateless component and the array is just passed in props. Updated answer.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the postArray to Summary.js so I can display it there?

Comment: Hi @Drew no errors already but when running the code, when Summary of Transactions is displayed, it displays the following values:

Summary of Transactions

Display content of postArray here

ID: NaN
AccountNumber:
Amount:
qNumber:
txNumber:
ID: NaN
AccountNumber:
Amount:
qNumber:
txNumber:
ID: NaN

Am I doing the assignment of values on the array correctly?  I have included the CashDeposit.js component.

Comment: Seems like a data integrity issue, `Summary` [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/laughing-snyder-xc25e?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) renders without issue. Issue may be in `insertTx` function, what are `this.txNumber`, `this.qNumber`, `this.accountNumber`, and `this.amount` values that you push into the array? Perhaps you mean `this.state.txNumber`, etc...? Also, make sure all your arithmetic operations are operating over numerical data types and not string values from inputs.

Comment: Code is already working after I added state.  You are right need to specify state on this.state.txNumber etc etc.

Comment: @Concorde Is your issue resolved then? FWIW if you define your propTypes then react can help catch errors where you pass strings instead of numbers in props that create value coercion bugs like what are likely seeing.

Comment: Yes its resolved.  What do you mean by FWIW?  Next thing to do now is to validate the encoded values, then insert into a database using Kafka.  For now I think I will use internal storage first.

Comment: @Concorde FWIW == "For What It's Worth"... using defined propTypes helps catch logical prop errors like accidentally passing values of the wrong type.